# sql: Calculate the correlations and convert rows into columns

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

So my current table has more than 100 fields and I am trying to calculate the correlations between the input variables and output variable, and then convert all those columns into rows.
For example, my current table looks like this:

| input_1 | input_2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 9 | 3 |
| 7 | 10 | 5 |
| 9 | 9 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 | 4 |

What I trying to achieve is:

| categories | correlation |
| --- | --- |
| input_1 | -0.594 |
| input_2 | -0.27 |

The query that I have written below gives me a correlation per each calculation. However, I was them converted into rows,

```
select (Avg(input1 * output) - (Avg(input1) * Avg(output))) / (stddev(input1) * stddev(output)) AS correlation

from a
```

Can you help how this can be achieved?
Thank you!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant here is the question per our last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''
select categories, correlation
from (
  select ''' || 
    string_agg('corr(' || category || ', output) as ' || category , ', ')
|| '''  from `project.dataset.table`
)
unpivot (correlation for categories in (''' || string_agg(category) || '''))
'''
from (
  select category from (
    select 
      array(
        select category
        from unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(\w+)":')) category
        where category != 'output'
      ) arr
    from `project.dataset.table` t
    limit 1
  ), unnest(arr) category
))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can notice - I am not using your heavy formula - rather I am using [CORR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#corr) built-in function